# what's the best way to make backup of my data?

Tags: backup, ubuntu-9.04

I have bought an Ubuntu server and I'm going to install several websites on it.

I was wondering how to perform backups of the websites.. stored in different folders in the /var/www folder.

For example, I could copy/paste the folders using a ftp client, but I was wondering what's the professional way to backup the data. Should I do it from unix and not ftp ?

Should I run a script ?
Should the backup be automatic ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what you want to do and what your machine is allowed to do.

I own a virtual server running Debian Lenny. I use [backup2l](http://backup2l.sourceforge.net/) which uses a good mix of differential, incremental and few full backups to save space. Because i'm not allowed to mount external filesystems to store my backups on, i let backup2l store its files on the vserver's drives. A post-backup-hook tells backup2l to use rsync (GREAT tool!) to sync my local backup archive with a remote one on a server at home.

Good Alternatives are:

- Custom script that uses rsync (that way you'll only have one Snapshot)
- [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/) (uses hardlinks to create snapshots of every state you have backed up available instantly. It's a bit like Apple's Time Machine - but AFAIK rsnapshot was there first ;) )
- Custom script that uses tar (to create archives of each FULL snapshot)
- One of the "enterprise ready" backup tools like [bacula](http://www.bacula.org/), [Amanda](http://www.amanda.org/), etc.
- Searching google for one of the numerous other solutions (see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/10things/?p=895), [here](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/backuptools1.htm) or [here](http://nixcraft.com/backup-recovery/15158-linux-backup-tools-recommendation.html))

[edit]
You should always send your data through an SSH tunnel, if you are storing your backups on another server (which i recommend!).

Comment: are "partitions" a backup solution ? In other words, are they useful if data are erased ? Or they cannot be compared to using another server ? could you give me some info about it ? thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "partitions"? Partitions like "partitions on a disk"? Then: no. Depending on how valuable the data is you REALLY should make a backup to another machine. Or at least another disk.

Answer (score 0):

While it may be old school, a simple combination of tar and scp may be all you need.  Whether it's scripted and / or scheduled depends on you.  It's not difficult to do either. A single command can pre authorize scp to work without requiring you to enter password every time.

You should not use simple FTP if you're at all worried about security.

Comment: ahm ok, but I don't get one point, if the content of my server for some reason is erased then I lose also the backups right ? What's are the other solutions ? Either having another server or creating partitions ?

Answer (score 0):

Also check out [rdiff-backup](http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/) and [backuppc](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/)